# How do I clear an error when typing in an EditText field?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-edittext

I have an EditText field wrapped in a TextInputLayout. If you click on the Save button, then this button checks whether the field is filled: if yes, then everything is ok, if not, then an error appears. If I enter the data after the error appears, then I need to click on the Save button again, so that the check for completeness passes again, and only then the error disappears. How can I make it so that the error disappears as soon as I start entering data in the field, and does not disappear only when the button is pressed again?

```
private fun checkStateTitleLayout() {
        val titleLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editTitleLayout)
        val checkTitleLayoutState = titleLayout.editText?.text?.toString()
        val fieldIsRequired = getString(R.string.fieldIsRequired)
        when {
            checkTitleLayoutState!!.isEmpty() -> {
                titleLayout.error = fieldIsRequired
            }
            else -> {
                titleLayout.error = null
                titleLayout.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDITED:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_item)

        val saveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.saveButton)
        val titleLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editTitleLayout)
        titleLayout.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                titleLayout.error = null
                titleLayout.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        })

        saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkStateTitleLayout()
        }
}

private fun checkStateTitleLayout() {
        val titleLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editTitleLayout)
        val checkTitleLayoutState = titleLayout.editText?.text?.toString()
        val fieldIsRequired = getString(R.string.fieldIsRequired)

        if (checkTitleLayoutState!!.isEmpty()) titleLayout.error = fieldIsRequired
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `TextWatcher` on that `EditText`. When ever there is a change in the text, the corresponding function will be triggered and will remove the error.

```
val titleLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.editTitleLayout)
titleLayout.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        titleLayout.error = null
    }
})
```

We only use `afterTextChanged()` because only that's required in this case. Using this will make your app work as expected.

Comment: Something is wrong, because my field is completely free of error. When I click on the Save button, I get no validation, nothing happens, even the error does not appear when the field is empty. And if I put the line `titleLayout.error = fieldIsRequired` before `addTextChangedListener`, then this error is triggered every time it is clicked. What can you advise?

Comment: @Anderson Wait a min, where did you put the code I've answered?  Don't put it inside `checkStateTitleLayout()` function. Put it after the code where all these `TextEdit` and `Buttons` are initialised. It will work like a charm.

Comment: @Anderson, if you still didn't get, please post your entire code of the file and I'll make correction and post it back.